# Eclipse Android library import keep removing itself

Tags: android, eclipse

I have just started a new android project, and I want to import some project I have found on Github.

I have seen a ton of these questions about how to import other projects as libraries, and the answer is always the same. 
So, I import like I am suppose to do, and have the following:
[image]

Then, I press OK, and the stupid library is not added. If I revisit this import page I see how only appcompat is added, and not Caldorid, even though I just did it.

My first guess would be the slash turning the opposed direction, but thats not something I can change.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hoooly f*ck, thanks man.. :P

Comment: You Welcome Peter :D ........ I used to stuck for many hours in this, at my starting :) Project name is NIGHT SHIFT :D

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error. To manage it, I copied the projects I wanted to use to my workspace and added again. The problem was solved. To do this, try to delete the project and import again. After your you select the project, check the checkbox to copy the project into your workspace. Then go to Properties>Android and add them again.
I hope this helps you yoo!